# Create a HashSet By Enumeration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT_INDICATOR")
public class Project_Indicator {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Indicator indicator;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;
    @NotNull
    private int year;
    // here I want create List (HashSet) with enumeration of months
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Indicator getIndicator() {
        return indicator;
    }
    public void setIndicator(Indicator indicator) {
        this.indicator = indicator;
    }
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }
    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}
```

This Project_Indicator class must contain an attribute wish is a List of months (jan until december) I want create a list with keys are (jan until dec) and each month have an attribute for example int value, then I want to do this :

```
int value=mySet.get("July");
```

please just I want an idea (or other Idea) if you understood my problem.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to use Java 8 you can use the new [Date and Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Specifically, you will find the new [Month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum useful:

```
Month month = Month.JULY;
int value = month.getValue();   // value == 7
```

If you would like your own month / value association you can use an EnumMap:

```
Map<Month, Integer> map = EnumMap<>(Month.class);
map.put(Month.JULY, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using an enum with a small static function that returns the ordinal of the month based on the lower-cased version of the string value passed in. This should be fairly robust. Also you do not have to use a collection, such as HashSet to achieve it. You need no import statements whatsoever. Here is some example code to display the concept.

```
public class MonthNumbers {

public enum months {
    JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER;

    public static int getMonth(String monthName) {
        for(months m : months.values()) {
            if(m.toString().toLowerCase().equals(monthName.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                return m.ordinal();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("January is " + months.getMonth("january"));
System.out.println("February is " + months.getMonth("February"));
System.out.println("March is " + months.getMonth("mArCh"));
System.out.println("April is " + months.getMonth("APRIL"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is just a soft variation on the enum from Scott Shipp above.
If you want to assign a specific number to each month you can use an enumeration constructor.
(the example uses 7 for Feb to show that the number you choose does not matter to the implementation).

```
public enum MonthAbbreviation
{
    Jan(1),
    Feb(7);

    private final int monthValue;

    private MonthAbbreviation(final int monthValue)
    {
        this.monthValue = monthValue;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return monthValue;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MonthAbbreviation monthAbbreviation;

        monthAbbreviation = MonthAbbreviation.valueOf("Jan");
        System.out.println(
            "Month: " +
            monthAbbreviation.toString() +
            " value: " +
            monthAbbreviation.getValue());

        monthAbbreviation = MonthAbbreviation.valueOf("Feb");
        System.out.println(
            "Month: " +
            monthAbbreviation.toString() +
            " value: " +
            monthAbbreviation.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your reponse, But I use an Entity class it will be a table in the database the problem is the Project_Indicator  Entity (each one) have 12 month (jan until dec) for example 
the project_indicator p1 have in jan 20% in feb 10% ... until dec 50%. it like the OneToMany relation so each project_indicator have many month wish are static (12 month), my Idea it not better to do an entity named Month and do OneToMany relation with project_indicator because I know the number of months ;). in this case I do this:

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "PROJECT_INDICATOR")
   public class Project_Indicator {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
private Indicator indicator;
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
private Project project;
@NotNull
private int year;
public enum Months {
    JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER;

    public static int getMonth(String monthName) {
        for(Months m : Months.values()) {
            if(m.toString().toLowerCase().equals(monthName.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                return m.ordinal();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

here when I generate my tables from entity they will not generate and I haven't error message, I think the problem is

```
private Map<Months,Integer> months;
```

How I resolve it.
Thanx.